# How to put an euro symbol in html R plotly graph?

Tags: r, r-markdown, plotly

I have just installed the latest version of R Plotly (4.5.2), everything is great, just a little problem : if I try to make an html page with a plotly graph including an hovertext with the euro symbol in it, previously, I just used the code € but it seems not to work. It's surprising because there's no problem if I look in the viewer of RStudio, but when I export the file in html and read it in chrome, it is not working (I see € instead of the euro symbol).

Here's my code :

```
require(plotly)
require(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  mutate(hovertext = paste("Sepal.length : ",Sepal.Length,"K&euro;<br> Sepal.Width : ",Sepal.Width)) %>%
    plot_ly(x=~Sepal.Length,y=~Sepal.Width,text=~hovertext)
```

Comment: Have you already used `\u20ac` instead of `&euro`?

Comment: I hadn't, but it works fine, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons discussed [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/733#issuecomment-250000079), plotly.js dropped support for HTML entities, but you can supply unicode (as the comment suggests)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I still find it odd that it works with &euro; in RStudio and not in htlml but can live with it :)